# JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource, offset=6

Tags: websphere-8, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to create a JDBC data source in WebSphere. Testing the connection returns the error message:

> JVMCFRE003 bad major version;
>   class=com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource,
>   offset=6

my environment and configuration:

```
WebSphere 8.5.5.13
JDK 1.7_64
JDBC driver: sqljdbc41.jar
OS: Linux eagnmnmed294 3.0.101-108.68-default #1 SMP Mon Aug 13 18:53:23 UTC 2018 (ef94234) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

SystemOut.log starts with:

> ************ Start Display Current Environment ************ WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.13 [ND 8.5.5.13 cf131801.05] [IBMJAVA7 7.0.10.15
>   cf131751.02] [IBMJAVA8 8.0.5.6 cf131751.02] running wi th process name
>   eagnmnmed294Network\eagnmnmed294\ploc_sit_294 and process id 47449
>   Host Operating System is Linux, version 3.0.101-108.68-default Java
>   version = 1.7.0, Java Runtime Version = pxa6470sr10fp20-20180221_01
>   (SR10 FP20), Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IB M J9 VM
>   was.install.root = /opt/WebSphere/AppServer855 user.install.root =
>   /opt/WebSphere/AppServer855/profiles/eagnmnmed294 Java Home =
>   /opt/WebSphere/AppServer855/java_1.7_64/jre

I have also tried with another version of driver:
sqljdbc42.jar

I got the same error.

What I am missing here?

Appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**, log info:

> [9/28/18 11:05:19:756 CDT] 00000106 DataSourceCon E   DSRA8040I:
>   Failed to connect to the DataSource "".  Encountered
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version;
>   class=com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource,
>   offset=6
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:273)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:74)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:563)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:474)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:77)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1059)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:488)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:452)
>           at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:701)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:680)
>           at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663)
>           at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663)
>           at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:618)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:693)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:680)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663)
>           at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:288)
>           at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.loadDataSourceClass(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1368)
>           at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper$5.run(DSConfigurationHelper.java:2351)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>           at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.testConnectionForGUI(DSConfigurationHelper.java:2349)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnectionToDataSource2(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:556)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnection(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:484)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
>           at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:424)
>           at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
>           at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
>           at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
>           at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
>           at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
>           at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
>           at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
>           at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.ResourceMBeanHelper.testNode(ResourceMBeanHelper.java:860)
>           at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.ResourceMBeanHelper.testConnection(ResourceMBeanHelper.java:292)
>           at com.ibm.ws.console.resources.database.jdbc.DataSourceDetailAction.testConnection(DataSourceDetailAction.java:713)
>           at com.ibm.ws.console.resources.database.jdbc.DataSourceCollectionAction.execute(DataSourceCollectionAction.java:339)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1238)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1238)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>           at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:967)
>           at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:514)
>           at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:335)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>           at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) : {2}. [9/28/18 11:05:19:765 CDT] 00000106 MBeanHelper   E   Could not
>   invoke an operation on object:
>   WebSphere:name=DataSourceCfgHelper,process=dmgr,platform=dynamicproxy,node=eagnmnmed294Manager,version=8.5.5.13,type=DataSourceCfgHelper,mbeanIdentifier=DataSourceCfgHelper,cell=eagnmnmed294Network,spec=1.0
>   because of an mbean exception: java.sql.SQLException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version;
>   class=com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource,
>   offset=6

Comment: Looks like this is an ND install, are you running test connection from a Node or the DMGR?

Comment: I would also double check that you don't have both jars configured anywhere on your classpath since the sqljdbc42.jar requires Java 8.

Comment: I use the WebSphere Admin Console to create/configure/test the JDBC. No, sqljdbc42.jar is not in the class path.

Comment: Does the system.out file you posted the header of contain the error?

Comment: Yes, please see my update.